# Meaning of the word "including" with "and/or"

Tags: meaning, ambiguity, conjunctions

Consider these two sentences:

1. This shop sells cars from different brands, including Audi, BMW, **and** Opel.
2. This shop sells cars from different brands, including Audi, BMW, **or** Opel.

Does sentence 1 imply that the shop sells cars which are exclusively Audi, BMW, or Opel?

Does sentence 2 imply that the shop sells cars which are exclusively Audi, BMW, or Opel?

Comment: They both mean essentially the same thing, though #2 isn't very well worded.

Comment: To my mind, ***or*** simply doesn't make sense in this context.

Answer (score 3):

Using "or" gives the impression that you are sure that they sell Audi and you think that they sell either BMW or Opel but you aren't sure which.

Using 'including' implies the exact opposite of 'exclusively', it means that they sell other brands as well as the ones you have listed.

Also English speakers don't speak of places where cars are sold as 'shops'. Large establishments with enclosed sales spaces, particularly those selling new cars, are called 'showrooms' or 'dealerships', smaller ones selling used cars are mostly called 'car lots' and, sometimes, a British English speaker will still call a small car lot a 'garage' which we used to use before we adopted the originally American 'car lot'.

Answer (score 0):

“Including” implies that the shop sells ALL these brands but possibly others, INCLUDING (BUT NOT LIMITED TO) Audi, BMW, and Opel.

Sentence 2 literally means that the shop sells one brand OR another, whichever it feels like selling. Sentence 1 is correct. Neither sentence says that the shop sells exclusively the brands named.

“The shop sells different brands, namely Audi, BMW, and Opel”. This way you make clear the shop sells only these brands, exclusively.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example that you used "and", in my idea it will say that the sells only this three brand "Audi, BMW, Opel".
But in the second example that you used "or", it will indicate that the shop sells "Audi, BMW" and maybe they sells "Opel" also.

Comment: No. ' all the leading brands including A, B, and C' means 'A, B, C, and all the other leading brands'.